# Clip & save layer using OpenLayers 2

Tags: vector, web-mapping, clip, openlayers-2

I ma currently developing a web mapping app. How do I make it possible for my app to clip and save area of interests or area I am working on. I can create a vector layer, modify it and delete if I want to, but how can I clip using OpenLayers 2.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using canvas.

Here's a [working solution](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/):

> **html2canvas**
>
> This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of
>   it, directly on the users browser.  The screenshot is based on the DOM
>   and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it
>   does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on
>   the information available on the page.

And some [examples](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html).

Edit: You may be able to use GeoJson.write() to serialize your vector object. Here's [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824385/5112932) on the matter.

Comment: I read the question as asking for a "clip, zip and ship" of vector data.  Your answer does not seem to describe a vector data download.

Comment: @PolyGeo you're likely correct, I've edited the post to better provide for 'clipping' a vector object.